# Структура маршрутизации, как лучше для сео?

Tags: seo, чпу

Создаю маршрутизацию сайту хотелось бы узнать какой вариант будет лучше для SEO:

1)Структура типа:
www.site.ru/gorod/razdel затем глубже www.site.ru/gorod/razdel/podrazdel
2)Структура типа:
www.site.ru/gorod/razdel затем более глубже www.site.ru/gorod/podrazdel

С одной стороны в первом варианте структура более правильно соблюдена, что нравится поисковикам, с другой стороны слышал что чем ближе к URL раздел с названием включающий ключевое слово тем лучше.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Основное требование для правильного SEO - это **достижения цели пользователем с применением максимум 3 кликов**. Например, пользователь зашёл на вашу главную страницу и увидел там в своём городе интересный для него продукт/услугу. Создайте такую структуру, чтобы он через 2 клика зашел на страницу с этим продуктом/услугой. Не акцентируйте ваше внимание на поисковиках, но на удобстве для пользователей. Именно они создают трафик на ваш сайт, поисковый рейтинг сайта и преобразуются в ваших клиентов.

Answer (score 0):

Для сео лучше чтобы контент на вашей странице, соответствовал ожиданиям пользователя.

Чем проще и понятнее, будет url тем лучше. Используйте второй вариант: один блок URL – обозначение раздела, а далее один адрес для конкретной страницы:

“Интересные места в городе Москва”:  **/moscow/places**

цитата из [справки Яндекса](https://yandex.ru/support/webmaster/recommendations/site-structure.xml?lang=ru) для вебмастеров

> “Желательно, чтобы вид URL давал представление о том, что содержится на соответствующей странице.”

Comment: Но для меня как пользователя намного удобнее был бы первый вариант

Comment: Про контент оно понятно, исходя из “Желательно, чтобы вид URL давал представление о том, что содержится на соответствующей странице.” Что будет более точно передавать представление? смотрите  имеется сайт ломбарды в Москве, в нем есть разделы автоломбард ломбард недвижимости и т.д. в них подразделы кредит под залог птс, кредит под залог авто. На мой взгляд более точно передает информацию первый вариант, т.е. www.site.ru/avtolombard/zalog-pod-pts нежели www.site.ru/zalog-pod-pts

Comment: Тем более есть такая вещь как "хлебные крошки" , которая сообщает информацию поисковикам о структуре сайта и дает неплохой плюс к релевантности сайта разве не правильно соблюдать ту же структуру в URL сайта?

Comment: @ДанилШуваев чтобы избежать вложенности, я советую использовать этот вариант, www.site.ru/zalog-pod-pts/article01 / Для самого раздела, согласен, лучше так www.site.ru/avtolombard/zalog-pod-pts. Но чтобы в будущем уйти от длинных адресов как раз подойдет второй вариант. Вы будете добавлять новые разделы, удалять их, а url будет всегда коротким ясным и понятным www.site.ru/zalog-pod-pts/article512

Comment: @ДанилШуваев о структуре сайта лучше сообщать через sitemap/ Это стандартный способ.